# tmuxinator installed but no mux?

Tags: arch-linux, tmux

I am running Arch (with zsh) and I am trying to follow the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmux) for setting up tmux. I want tmux to start automatically.

I've installed tmuxinator as per the instructions, but I get the error:

> command not found: mux

I'm not really sure why it can't find mux. I do have `tmuxinator` installed:

```
~ ❯ which tmuxinator
/usr/bin/tmuxinator
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You have most likely typed `mux` instead of `tmux` somewhere in some configuration file or shell startup file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the Wiki [says to do](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmux#Autostart_tmux_with_default_tmux_layout)!

Comment: Does it work after you do `hash -r` in `bash` (or `rehash` in `zsh`)?

Comment: I just ran `rehash` in `zsh`, but nope, still get the same error.